# How to apply onClick in the input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

As you can this is a string js and I want to use onClick on the input whose view is being toggled by selecting the boolean value edit. Please suggest how to use onchnage here.

Already tried normal HTML onchange (not working)

```
onchange="${onchnage}"
```

Pls, suggest if you happen to know the answer.

```
    export const DefaultNode = (d, selectedNodeIds, edit, fomatOptions, inputOnclick) => {
    
    const mainData = d.data.data
  
    return `<div style='background:${selectedNodeIds.length!==0 ? (selectedNodeIds.includes(d.data.id) ? `rgba(${ fomatOptions.nodeBg.r }, ${ fomatOptions.nodeBg.g }, ${ fomatOptions.nodeBg.b }, ${ fomatOptions.nodeBg.a })`: "#fff"): `rgba(${ fomatOptions.nodeBg.r }, ${ fomatOptions.nodeBg.g }, ${ fomatOptions.nodeBg.b }, ${ fomatOptions.nodeBg.a })`}; 
        color:${selectedNodeIds.length!==0 ?(selectedNodeIds.includes(d.data.id) ?`rgba(${ fomatOptions.textColor.r }, ${ fomatOptions.textColor.g }, ${ fomatOptions.textColor.b }, ${ fomatOptions.textColor.a })`:'#000'): `rgba(${ fomatOptions.textColor.r }, ${ fomatOptions.textColor.g }, ${ fomatOptions.textColor.b }, ${ fomatOptions.textColor.a })`}'
                    
                    
                    class=${`"w-[250px] p-3  rounded-[15px] relative border-[3px] h-[140px] ${selectedNodeIds.includes(d.data.id)? 'drop-shadow-md' :"shadow"} ${ selectedNodeIds.includes(d.data.id) && fomatOptions.fontFamily.value}"`}>
            <div class='flex justify-between  w-full  '>
            <div class="">
                ${edit? `<input onclick='${inputOnclick}' class="fullName text-[13px] font-semibold" value="${mainData.name}"/>` : `<div class=" text-[13px] font-semibold">${mainData.name} </div>`}
                <div class=" text-[11px] opacity-70 mt-0.5 font-medium">${mainData.position } </div>
                <div class='mt-2'>
                    <div class=" text-[11px] opacity-70 mt-0.5 font-medium">${mainData.email } </div>
                    <div class=" text-[11px] opacity-70 mt-0.5 font-medium">${mainData.phone } </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <img class='w-10 h-10 mr-2 rounded-[10px]' src=${mainData.imgUrl} />
    </div>
    <div class='flex pt-4 justify-between items-center'>
        <p class='text-[10px] font-medium uppercase bg-theme-gray px-2 text-black rounded-full py-0.5'>${mainData.department}</p>
        <p class='text-[10px] font-medium uppercase mr-2'>${mainData.location}</p>
    </div>
    ${((selectedNodeIds.includes(d.data.id))) ? `<div class="absolute left-4 -top-5 font-semibold text-[10px] p-1 bg-gray-400 text-white rounded-t-md">
        Selected
    </div>`: `<p></p>`}
</div>`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're missing here is the different naming conventions for default HTML event listeners in React, not all of your code is here so I'm assuming you do not have a custom function called onchange, but in React its called onChange (or onClick, etc) so you're looking something like this for your code snippet.

```
onChange="${onchnage}"
```

Also double-check to make sure you have all your syntax and spelling correct. Also for writing better JSX for returning HTML elements you can write code like the following

```
 return (
   <div>
     <p>Text here</p>
   </div>
 );
```